# 403 Forbidden while Calling External PHP in Wordpress

Tags: php, http-status-code-403

I have created a new Page in Wordpress. On this page, I have put the following HTML code:

```
Please click this <a href="http://sitename.com/blog/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/statistics.php" title="link">link</a> to view the details.
```

statistics.php has the code to query the backend MySQL database, fetch the details and display in a table format.

however, when I click the link on the Wordpress Page I get a 403 forbidden message.

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /blog/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/statistics.php on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I have tried setting the permissions of the PHP file to both, 644 and 755. Error still persists.

I have even tried putting a simple code like this in the PHP file:

```
<?php echo "welcome"?>
```

Even then, the same 403 forbidden error.

Now, I have another page on this Wordpress Site. In that page I have an HTML Form that sends a POST request to a PHP file called process.php which is present in the same directory as statistics.php. That page works properly.

So, I tried replacing the URL in my new page from statistics.php to the process.php. That does not give a 403 forbidden error.

Why is it that I am unable to access one PHP file from my wordpress page? Am I allowed to link only to one external PHP file from wordpress page?

both statistics.php and process.php have the same permissions. However, while one page is able to easily access process.php, the other page gives an error for statistics.php.

Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked your .htaccess file for any too globally defined RewriteRules? In any case...you should check the server log files to find out exactly what happens when you try to open the page.

Answer (score 0):

The directory you have your script under is not readable and neither should it be. It is used by wordpress to store the themes, and this directory can only be read by wordpress in order to output the theme to the front end.

Try placing your scripts in a directory which is not controlled/needed by WordPress. i.e., on your public root, create a new readable directory and place under that directory whichever scripts you need.